# Updating an array in Firestore using arrayUnion

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to add a value to an array inside a collection in Firestore.
I've followed the documentation but I always get an error saying:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: FirebaseError: Function
> DocumentReference.update() called with invalid data.
> Unsupported
> field value: a custom object (found in field players in document
> seasons/CNClnl0NhvVxmk32sKe2)

Note that the array is empty as is. But it did contain data initially with the same result.

I've tried manually inserting the seasonId without luck.

Here is my code:

```
const seasonRef = db.collection("seasons").doc(seasonId);
  await seasonRef
    .update({
      players: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(userId),
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err.message);
    });
```

db.js:

```
const firebase = require("firebase");
const config = require("./config");

firebase.initializeApp(config);

const db = firebase.firestore();

module.exports = db;
```

I've tried having admin declared both as:

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
```

and:

```
const admin = require("../data/firebase");
```

which references:

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const config = require("./config");

admin.initializeApp(config);

module.exports = admin;
```

The latter I use for authenticating tokens generated in the frontend.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the [complete minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the error.  What you're showing is incomplete because we can't see how you create `db`.  We should be able to take everything you show here, copy it, and see the same behavior.

Comment: @DougStevenson, I've added the db.js content

Comment: What is `userId` in your code (since that is likely the value that is causing the problem)?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen a simple string that is generated by Firestore, in this case: DD2elAn4XaWzeOquw2DtOucS5mk2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing the Firestore client and Admin SDKs.  That's not going to work.

You are importing the web client SDK like this:

```
const firebase = require("firebase");
```

And you are importing the Admin SDK like this:

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
```

They are different SDKs with different APIs.  You can't use the `FieldValue.arrayUnion()` from the Admin SDK as input to code calling the client SDK.  While the APIs certainly look similar, they are just not the same.  You should use either one or the other, not both.  If you are running on a nodejs backend, you should probably just use the Admin SDK.